# Problem in getting file size while uploading

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, 2016, file-upload

I  am trying to get the file size while uploading it using `properties.AfterProperties["vti_filesize"].ToString()` but it always returns 0 while I am uploading ZIP files.

Answer (score 1):

The "vti_filesize" can get file size for a document file. It is always null or zero when dealing with a folder.

A ZIP file is **a zipped folder**. Thus, you get the zero value.

Comment: then what to do to get a zipped file size.